# How can I select 2+ lines using the keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

When holding <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>left/right</kbd>, I can select whole words as opposed to one letter. However, I cannot find a similar command for vertical lines: <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>up/down</kbd> only selects one line at a time.

How can I perform a similar action for paragraphs or more than one line?

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard shortcuts you specified will allow you to select a paragraph at a time if you start with the first word and hit Option + Shift + Up/Down.

You can also triple click one of the words in a paragraph to select the whole paragraph.